# Moving a specific line under another using sed

Tags: linux, shell, sed

I need to find and replace entryUUID with newrdn and then move that line under another line. This text file will have over 500k changetypes so moving to a specific line number will not work.

Original lines in text file:

```
dn: uid=test@testing.com,ou=people,dc=example,dc=com
changetype: modrdn
deleteoldrdn: 1
newsuperior: ou=people,dc=example,dc=com
entryUUID: 6277b4d4e3-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxx
```

I want to replace entryUUID with newrdn and then move this line below the line starting with changetype.

ideal output:

```
dn: uid=test@testing.com,ou=people,dc=example,dc=com
changetype: modrdn
newrdn: 6277b4d4e3-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxx
deleteoldrdn: 1
newsuperior: ou=people,dc=example,dc=com
```

I'm using the following command; but, it is not working as expected (adding a new incorrect entry instead of moving the line)

```
sed -i '/^changetype:*/a;'s/entryUUID:/newrdn:/g' file.txt
```

Comment: Oh, are there multiple cases of this in the file, or just the one?

Comment: @Shawn there are multiple cases of this in the file.

Answer (score 1):

One way using `sed`:

Example file with multiple entries:

```
dn: uid=test@testing.com,ou=people,dc=example,dc=com
changetype: modrdn
deleteoldrdn: 1
newsuperior: ou=people,dc=example,dc=com
entryUUID: 6277b4d4e3-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxx
---
dn: uid=test@testing.com,ou=people,dc=example,dc=com
changetype: modrdn
deleteoldrdn: 1
newsuperior: ou=people,dc=example,dc=org
entryUUID: 7277b4d4e3-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxx
```

```sh
sed -e '/^deleteoldrdn:/{N;h;d}; /^entryUUID:/{s/^entryUUID:/newrdn:/;G}' input.txt
dn: uid=test@testing.com,ou=people,dc=example,dc=com
changetype: modrdn
newrdn: 6277b4d4e3-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxx
deleteoldrdn: 1
newsuperior: ou=people,dc=example,dc=com
---
dn: uid=test@testing.com,ou=people,dc=example,dc=com
changetype: modrdn
newrdn: 7277b4d4e3-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxx
deleteoldrdn: 1
newsuperior: ou=people,dc=example,dc=org
```

#### How it works:

`/^deleteoldrnd:/{N;h;d}`

Each time a line that starts with `deleteoldrnd:` is read, also read the next line and add it to the current *pattern space* (`N`), replace the current *hold space* with the pattern space (`h`), delete the pattern space and begin anew with a new line (`d`).

`/^entryUUID:/{s/^entryUUID:/newrdn:/;G}`

Each time a line that starts with `entryUUID:` is read, change the prefix to `newrdn:`, then append the hold space to the pattern space (`G`), (The hold space at this point is the `deleteoldrdn` and `newsuperior` lines immediately preceding in the original file). The pattern space then automatically gets printed out.

If you're using GNU sed (Which seems likely since you tagged this [linux]), a variation is:

```sh
sed -e '/^deleteoldrdn:/{N;h;z;N;s/\nentryUUID:/newrdn:/;G}' input.txt
```

which uses the GNU extension `z` to erase the pattern space before reading the UUID line in the same command sequence, instead of splitting it up into two.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `sed -i` to edit the file in-place, you can also use `ed`, which, since it treats a file as a whole instead of processing an isolated line at a time, has commands to move lines around, which simplifies things a lot. Using the same input file as my `sed` answer:

```
$ ed -s input.txt <<'EOF'
g/^entryUUID:/s/^entryUUID:/newrdn:/\ 
m -3
w
EOF
$ cat input.txt
dn: uid=test@testing.com,ou=people,dc=example,dc=com
changetype: modrdn
newrdn: 6277b4d4e3-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxx
deleteoldrdn: 1
newsuperior: ou=people,dc=example,dc=com
---
dn: uid=test@testing.com,ou=people,dc=example,dc=com
changetype: modrdn
newrdn: 7277b4d4e3-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxx
deleteoldrdn: 1
newsuperior: ou=people,dc=example,dc=org
```

#### How it works

For each line starting with `entryUUID:` (`g/^entryUUID:/`), first change that line so it starts with `newrdn:`, and then move it up two lines (`m` moves to *after* the destination address, hence `-3` instead of `-2`.) Then write the modified file after making all the changes.

Putting the commands in a heredoc instead of just entering them interactively makes it easier to use in a script. Using single quotes around the `EOF` is needed to keep the backslash from being eaten.

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -n '/^changetype:/{p;:a;n;/^entryUUID:/bb;H;ba;:b;s//newrdn:/p;z;x;s/.//};p' file
```

Print any lines until one beginning `changetype:`, print this line and gather up the lines following it into the hold space until a line beginning `entryUUID:`. Replace that string by `newrdn:` and print the current line. Append the lines collected in the hold space less the leading newline and print them. Print all other lines.

An alternative solution:

```
sed '/^changetype:/{:a;N;s/^entryUUID:/newrnd:/m;Ta;s/\(\n.*\)\(\n.*\)/\2\1/}' file
```